# Implement Hashable for all class types automatically

Tags: swift

I copy/paste this anytime I need a Hashable class type:

```
func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { return hasher.combine(ObjectIdentifier(self)) }
static func ==(lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
    return ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
}
```

Since the `ObjectIdentifier` is always unique for an object, this seems reasonable and is recommended in many answers and forums.

First question is -- why can't class types automatically do this so they are implicitly Hashable just as structs are?

Second, more interesting, how can I write an extension that does this for me?

I tried:

```
protocol ClassHash: AnyObject {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher)
    static func ==(lhs: ClassHash, rhs: ClassHash) -> Bool
}

extension ClassHash {
    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) { return hasher.combine(ObjectIdentifier(self)) }
    static func ==(lhs: ClassHash, rhs: ClassHash) -> Bool {
        return ObjectIdentifier(lhs) == ObjectIdentifier(rhs)
    }
}
```

Compiler still complains, however, that a class that declares itself to be `ClassHash` is still not equatable. Am I missing something or is this just not possible?

Comment: Do you really want this, we already know that an object that points to another object is the same and thus equal to that other object. Isn’t it more interesting to compare objects that have been created separately for equality and then of course we want to use any attribute _except_ the object identifier in such comparison. This kind of autogenerated comparison looks  a bit dangerous to me. If you still want this you are not far off with your current code but it should be an extension to `Hashable`

Comment: You did not write that ClassHash conforms to Hashable